# Get HZ & BW from Rostopic Programatically

Tags: ros, rostopic, bandwidth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I want to write a program in python and I need the value of HZ and BW (on specific topic).
How can I do it (Using rostopic or something else)?

thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259709/get-hz-&-bw-from-rostopic-programatically/) by [matansar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29912/matansar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the same classes that the rostopic tool does to do this. If you `import rostopic`, you will find in that package several classes that gather statistics about topics. For example, the `ROSTopicHz` class is used to get the publishing rate. You can see how to use these classes by mimicking the functions that call them, such as `_rostopic_hz`. Basically, the statistics-gathering class instance is created, the topic of interest is subscribed to, and the callback on the instance of the statistics class is passed to the subscription. Then, after giving some time for messages to be processed, you can call a method of the stats class to get the current result.

Here's an example:

```
> import rospy, rostopic
> rospy.init_node('blurglesplort')
> r = rostopic.ROSTopicHz(-1)
> s = rospy.Subscriber('/joint_states', rospy.AnyMsg, r.callback_hz, callback_args='/joint_states')
> rospy.sleep(1)
> r.print_hz(['/joint_states'])
average rate: 46.186
        min: 0.000s max: 0.103s std dev: 0.03928s window: 643
```

Note that this is probably not a public API. If so, the API may change without notice.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matansar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29912/matansar/) on 2017-04-22**:
thank you very much!
but need a change: r.print_hz does not get param.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-23**:
Yes, it looks like the `print_hz` function changed between Jade and Kinetic, and I was testing on Kinetic.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2021-02-22**:
Could you help me, please? @geoff
[here](https://answers.ros.org/question/372389/get-hz-from-rostopic-for-subscribertopic-and-publishertopic/) is my question.

**Comment by [Sj-Amani](https://answers.ros.org/users/88870/sj-amani/) on 2021-11-04**:
If you want to **get** the param, use the **get_hz** method instead of **print_hz** [Ref](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rostopic/html/rostopic.ROSTopicHz-class.html):

```
r.get_hz('/joint_states')[0]
```

**get_hz** method returns a tuple of stat results: rate, min_delta, max_delta, std_dev, n+1.
The **rate** represents the **hz** i.e. [0].